# How to get cache of extension in acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I want to know how to get the extension cache of my graph i just made a `foreach` code to loop through my graph base cache but if I try doing it on my extension or custom fields I cant get them I want to know how I can get all of the extension cache for my `foreach` code

Here below I can get the graph of my instance by doing

```
foreach (APTran row in Base.Transactions.Cache.Cached)
{
}
```

But how can I get extension cache?

I want to get extension cache of my graph to get my custom field value inside the cache

```
foreach (APTranExt row in ?????) 
{   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call Get Extension when you have an instance of the base DAC available. `row` in your case is your instance of the base dac.

```
var rowExt = row.GetExtension<APTranExt>();
```

or

*(Preferred method based on recent Acumatica support case where the above does not work in some cases)*

```
var rowExt = PXCache<APTran>.GetExtension<APTranExt>(row);
```

So in your example use one of the calls above inside your loop of APTran.

If you need a graph extension you would use:

```
var graphExt = myGraphInstance.GetExtension<MyGraphExt>();
```